# Replace/substitute adversarial substring variables in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have three unescaped adversarial shell variables.

```
$mystring
$old
$new
```

Remember, all three strings are adversarial. They will contain special characters. They will contain everything possible to mess up the replace. If there is a loophole in your replace, the strings will exploit it.

What is the simplest function to replace $old with $new in $mystring?
(I couldn't find any solution in stack overflow for a generic substitution that will work in all cases).

Comment: Protection against adversarial examples is an issue when you're using tools -- like `sed` -- that pass data and code in-band with each other. As soon as you avoid that pattern, by keeping your instructions and data out-of-band, the specifics of what the data contains becomes moot. (Or almost moot -- a lot of the available tools are line-oriented, which is why I didn't suggest [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)'s `gsub_literal`, or the `in="$search" out="$replace" perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' ./*` example from that same source).

Comment: (...as those tools do still do The Right Thing and keep code and data out-of-band from each other, though, your worst-case is strings that fail to match when line boundaries are crossed, not injection attacks).

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing fancy here -- the only thing you need to do to ensure that your values are treated as literals in a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is to ensure that you're quoting the search value, as described in the relevant section of [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021#Variables):

```
result=${mystring/"$old"/$new}
```

Without the double quotes on the inside, `$old` would be interpreted as a fnmatch-style glob expression; with them, it's literal.

---

To operate on streams instead, consider `gsub_literal`, also described in BashFAQ #21:

```
# usage: gsub_literal STR REP
# replaces all instances of STR with REP. reads from stdin and writes to stdout.
gsub_literal() {
  # STR cannot be empty
  [[ $1 ]] || return

  # string manip needed to escape '\'s, so awk doesn't expand '\n' and such
  awk -v str="${1//\\/\\\\}" -v rep="${2//\\/\\\\}" '
    # get the length of the search string
    BEGIN {
      len = length(str);
    }

    {
      # empty the output string
      out = "";

      # continue looping while the search string is in the line
      while (i = index($0, str)) {
        # append everything up to the search string, and the replacement string
        out = out substr($0, 1, i-1) rep;

        # remove everything up to and including the first instance of the
        # search string from the line
        $0 = substr($0, i + len);
      }

      # append whatever is left
      out = out $0;

      print out;
    }
  '
}

some_command | gsub_literal "$search" "$rep"
```

...which can also be used for in-place replacement on files using techniques from the following (yet again taken from the previously-linked FAQ):

```
# Using GNU tools to preseve ownership/group/permissions
gsub_literal "$search" "$rep" < "$file" > tmp &&
  chown --reference="$file" tmp &&
  chmod --reference="$file" tmp &&
  mv -- tmp "$file"
```

Comment: If a general search and replace is this simple, I'm curious as to why sed is normally recommended as the solution for vanilla search and replace, when it can go wrong if the delimiter is present in the string?

Comment: Cargo-cult programming -- where people copy practices they've seen elsewhere without understanding the reasoning behind them -- is prevalent in shell: What's commonly seen and what's best practice differ perhaps more often than not.

Comment: ...that said, `sed` has considerably better throughput when operating on a large stream; you wouldn't want to use the code in this answer on a variable with a megabytes of content. If you needed robustness with good bulk performance, that's when I'd reach for one of the other approaches given in BashFAQ #21 -- the `awk`-backed `gsub_literal` function; Perl with content passed out-of-band via environment variables; etc.

Comment: @hrs, ...just to be clear, though -- while `sed` has better *throughput*, because it's an external tool there's substantial startup costs involved in invoking it; thus, if you're processing thousands of lines of content one at a time, calling `sed` once per line would be extremely slow, whereas the parameter expansion approach taken here avoids that startup cost. (You could have a loop read over the output of a *single invocation* of `sed` much more efficiently, but you don't want to write code that invokes `sed` over and over).